# Setting gnome-terminal window size from within ~/.bashrc

Tags: gnome-terminal, bashrc

It know that it is possible to pass the `--geometry=WxH` arguments when using launcher, but how to set this option with the `~/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the `wmctrl` package. Then, add this to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
HORIZONTAL=600
VERTICAL=400
wmctrl -r ":ACTIVE:" -e 0,-1,-1,${HORIZONTAL},${VERTICAL}
```

It will resize your active window (should be the terminal), to the size specified by the `${HORIZONTAL}` and `${VERTICAL}` variables. Note that these are measured in pixels. You can set your terminal's geometry to what you want, then use the `screenruler` package to measure the dimensions in pixels.

Hope this helps :)

EDIT: Actually you can run this to show the size of all the `gnome-terminal`'s that are open:

```
wmctrl -l -x -G | grep gnome-terminal.Gnome-terminal | awk '{ print "Horizontal: "$5" pixels; Vertical: "$6" pixels" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the following command in your `.bash_profile` file.

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=WIDTHxHEIGHT+XPOS+YPOS
```

In which:

- `WIDTH` is the width in characters
- `HEIGHT` is the height in rows
- `XPOS` is the X-positon in pixels
- `YPOS` is the Y-position in pixels

Notice that an `x` separates WIDTH from HEIGHT. A `+` separates the HEIGHT   from XPOS. Another `+` separates XPOS from the YPOS.

Comment: No effect on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS