# Gnome3 Terminal restores previous window size on focus loss

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

Sometimes when I resize a window in gnome 3 and then switch tasks, the window snaps back to it's previous size. How can I make it retain the size that I change it to?

For instance, if I drag at the sides of a terminal window to make it a new size it will resize, however when I click on any other window the size of the terminal will shrink back to exactly the same size it was before I resized it.

It might only be the terminal window that does this. Other windows I have seem retain their size.

Comment: please a little bit more details to be clear and avoid too wide range of answers ... what do you means for "making it stick" ?

Comment: it sounds like an environment bug or conflict ... if it isn't related to the Terminal settings then I think it can be some compiz overrides conflict.

Comment: i guess i can check the compiz settings... it's been a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently a bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1040885

They mentioned a workaround, select the first tab and resize. Apparently this only happens when the first tab isn't selected.

Answer (score 1):

Usual user settings for a Terminal window sizing based on the rows and columns.
Not a pixel size. So you need change Profile Preferences.

**Edit > Profile Preferences > General > Default Size ( columns / rows )**

Or to maintain different window sizes for Terminal you can create new profiles for each:

**Edit > Profiles > New**
Name your new profile and tune it.
Later you can switch them **Terminal > Change Profile**

Also window sizing templates already exist in menu **Terminal**

***Update:***

However, also look this Q/A:
[Setting gnome-terminal window size from within ~/.bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51122/setting-gnome-terminal-window-size-from-within-bashrc?rq=1)

it means that ~/.bashrc configuration can override **columns/rows** size.

Comment: Thanks, i tried changing the size by switching profiles, but it didn't retain the size when i switched windows. Default helps when creating a new terminal, but not the one I have presently. Even changing the size with the "Terminal" menu will not be retained by the Terminal when the window is switched.

Comment: I used the default profile size, created a new window, and merely moved my tabs to the new window. I guess that's the best that can be done now.

Comment: The answer does not specify this so I thought I would clarify. For some reason setting a Custom starting width and height in the Default profile suddenly gives the resulting terminal an ability to remember its dragged final size--having it as blank causes it to snap back